# How to position items in center of each list tag

Tags: html, css

I took a nav menu from cssdeck.com and customized it.

But, I can't center the small dots (#main > li:after) in the center of each list tags...

The only difference from the original I can find is the (left: 50%;) css in (#main > li:after), and if I add it to my css, all the dots gather in the center of whole #main nav.

I really can't figure out why it won't work on mine.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vksvsg2d/ this is the original one

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1z6kgf1w/ and this is mine

Answer (score 1):

Add this and it will work fine

```
nav a {
        display: block;
        position: relative;

    }
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1z6kgf1w/1/)**

Comment: Np @FrancesPark happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a relative position to it:

```
nav a {display: block; position: relative;}
```

Comment: oops, seems there's an answer before mine!

Comment: Just c the time difference ... you must have had a look even before posting your answer, just nitpicking :P